# Free wysiwyg html editor from which I can open directly an external editor for images

Tags: html, image, editor, wysiwyg

For writing of documentation in an HTML file containing text and self-created images I am looking for an HTML editor:

1. that is free,
2. wysiwyg,
3. cross-platform (nice, but at least for linux),
4. and from which I can **directly open an external image editor** (configurable, so that I can use my favourite one).

The html editors I have seen so far have no "one-click" solution for editing images which are linked in my html file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked out http://www.aptana.com/ or http://bluegriffon.org/?

Comment: Aptana is configurable but has no WYSIWYG html editor.
Bluegriffon is WYSIWYG, but cannot be configured to use an external image editor.

Any other ideas?

Comment: sorry... not really.. I use Sublime Text, but it's not wysiwyg at all!  :)